# Binary serialization library

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization

I am currently working on a binary serialization library written in C++11 for a personal project. I'd really like to have a review about my design, my implementation and everything else. The library is inspired from [`QDataStream`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html).

[Here](https://gitlab.com/Telokis/Sery) is the GitLab repository containing the project.

**Sery/Misc.hh**

```
#ifndef SERY_MISC_HH_
#define SERY_MISC_HH_

#define SERY_BEGIN_NAMESPACE namespace Sery {

#define SERY_END_NAMESPACE }

#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

SERY_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

template< bool B, class T = void >
using enable_if_t = typename ::std::enable_if<B, T>::type;

enum Endian
{
  LittleEndian,
  BigEndian
};

typedef std::int8_t   int8;
typedef std::int16_t  int16;
typedef std::int32_t  int32;
typedef std::int64_t  int64;

typedef std::uint8_t  uint8;
typedef std::uint16_t uint16;
typedef std::uint32_t uint32;
typedef std::uint64_t uint64;

namespace       detail
{
  inline Endian getSoftwareEndian()
  {
    int16       witness = 0x5501;
    int8        test = *((int8*)&witness);
    return (test == 1 ? Endian::LittleEndian : Endian::BigEndian);
  }
}

SERY_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // SERY_MISC_HH_
```

**Sery/Buffer.hh**

```
#ifndef SERY_BUFFER_HH_
#define SERY_BUFFER_HH_

#include <vector>
#include <Sery/IBuffer.hh>

SERY_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class   Buffer : public IBuffer
{
public:
  Buffer();
  Buffer(const char *buffer, uint32 size);
  ~Buffer();

public:
  virtual void              writeRaw(const char *buffer, uint32 size) final;
  virtual void              readRaw(char *buffer, uint32 size) final;
  virtual uint32            size() const final;
  virtual const char        *data() const final;

private:
  std::vector<char>         _buffer;
};

SERY_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // SERY_BUFFER_HH_
```

**Sery/Buffer.cpp**

```
#include <Sery/Buffer.hh>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string.h>

SERY_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

Buffer::Buffer()
  : _buffer()
{
}

Buffer::Buffer(const char *buffer, uint32 size)
  : _buffer(buffer, buffer + size)
{
}

Buffer::~Buffer()
{
}

void        Buffer::writeRaw(const char *buffer, uint32 size)
{
  _buffer.insert(_buffer.end(), buffer, buffer + size);
}

void        Buffer::readRaw(char *buffer, uint32 size)
{
  memcpy(buffer, _buffer.data(), size);
  _buffer.erase(_buffer.begin(), _buffer.begin() + size);
}

uint32      Buffer::size() const
{
  return ((uint32)_buffer.size());
}

const char  *Buffer::data() const
{
  return (_buffer.data());
}

SERY_END_NAMESPACE
```

**Sery/Stream.hh**

```
#ifndef SERY_STREAM_HH_
#define SERY_STREAM_HH_

#include <Sery/Misc.hh>

SERY_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class IBuffer;

class Stream
{
private:
  // Removing copy and move functions
  Stream(const Stream&) = delete;
  Stream(Stream&&)      = delete;
  Stream  &operator=(const Stream&) = delete;
  Stream  &operator=(Stream&&)      = delete;

private:
  static Endian   globalEndian;

public:
  static void     setGlobalEndian(Endian endian);
  static Endian   getGlobalEndian();

public:
  // Must be constructed with an IBuffer
  Stream(IBuffer &buffer);
  ~Stream();

public:
  // Proxies for lower level manipulation
  Stream  &writeRaw(const char *buffer, uint32 size);
  Stream  &readRaw(char *buffer, uint32 size);

public:
  void    setLocalEndian(Endian endian);
  Endian  getLocalEndian() const;

private:
  IBuffer &_buffer;
  Endian  _localEndian;
};


// (De)Serialization of a C-Style string
Stream  &operator<<(Stream &stream, const char *str);
Stream  &operator>>(Stream &stream, char *&str);

// (De)Serialization of all arithmetic types
template <class T, enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value> * = nullptr>
Stream  &operator<<(Stream &stream, T t);
template <class T, enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value> * = nullptr>
Stream  &operator>>(Stream &stream, T &t);

SERY_END_NAMESPACE

#include "detail/Stream_STD.hh" // Contains serialization for standard library

#endif // SERY_STREAM_HH_
```

**Sery/Stream.cpp**

```
#include <Sery/Stream.hh>
#include <Sery/IBuffer.hh>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

SERY_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

Stream::Stream(IBuffer &buffer)
: _buffer(buffer),
_localEndian(Stream::globalEndian)
{
}

Stream::~Stream()
{
}

Stream  &Stream::writeRaw(const char *buffer, uint32 size)
{
  _buffer.writeRaw(buffer, size);
  return (*this);
}

Stream  &Stream::readRaw(char *buffer, uint32 size)
{
  _buffer.readRaw(buffer, size);
  return (*this);
}

void    Stream::setLocalEndian(Endian endian)
{
  _localEndian = endian;
}

Endian  Stream::getLocalEndian() const
{
  return (_localEndian);
}

// Static members
Endian   Stream::globalEndian = Endian::BigEndian;

void     Stream::setGlobalEndian(Endian endian)
{
  globalEndian = endian;
}

Endian   Stream::getGlobalEndian()
{
  return (globalEndian);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////
// External functions for serialization //
//////////////////////////////////////////

// Templates for serializing arithmetics types
template <class T, enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value> *>
Stream    &operator<<(Stream &stream, T t)
{
  Endian  softwareEndian  = detail::getSoftwareEndian();
  Endian  currentEndian   = stream.getLocalEndian();
  char    buffer[sizeof(T)];
  const uint8 *p = reinterpret_cast<const uint8 *>(&t);

  for (size_t index = 0;
       index < sizeof(T);
       ++index)
  {
    if (currentEndian == softwareEndian)
      buffer[index] = *p++;
    else
      buffer[sizeof(T) - index - 1] = *p++;
  }

  stream.writeRaw(buffer, sizeof(T));
  return (stream);
}

// Explicit instantiations of templates functions
template Stream &operator<< <int8>        (Stream &, int8);
template Stream &operator<< <int16>       (Stream &, int16);
template Stream &operator<< <int32>       (Stream &, int32);
template Stream &operator<< <int64>       (Stream &, int64);
template Stream &operator<< <uint8>       (Stream &, uint8);
template Stream &operator<< <uint16>      (Stream &, uint16);
template Stream &operator<< <uint32>      (Stream &, uint32);
template Stream &operator<< <uint64>      (Stream &, uint64);
template Stream &operator<< <float>       (Stream &, float);
template Stream &operator<< <double>      (Stream &, double);
template Stream &operator<< <long double> (Stream &, long double);

// Templates for deserializing arithmetics types
template <class T, enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value> *>
Stream    &operator>>(Stream &stream, T &t)
{
  Endian  softwareEndian  = detail::getSoftwareEndian();
  Endian  currentEndian   = stream.getLocalEndian();
  char  buffer[sizeof(T)];
  stream.readRaw(buffer, sizeof(T));

  uint8 *p = reinterpret_cast<uint8 *>(&t);

  for (size_t index = 0;
       index < sizeof(T);
       ++index)
  {
    if (currentEndian == softwareEndian)
      *p++ = buffer[index];
    else
      *p++ = buffer[sizeof(T) - index - 1];
  }

  return (stream);
}

// Explicit instantiations of templates functions
template Stream &operator>> <int8>        (Stream &, int8 &);
template Stream &operator>> <int16>       (Stream &, int16 &);
template Stream &operator>> <int32>       (Stream &, int32 &);
template Stream &operator>> <int64>       (Stream &, int64 &);
template Stream &operator>> <uint8>       (Stream &, uint8 &);
template Stream &operator>> <uint16>      (Stream &, uint16 &);
template Stream &operator>> <uint32>      (Stream &, uint32 &);
template Stream &operator>> <uint64>      (Stream &, uint64 &);
template Stream &operator>> <float>       (Stream &, float &);
template Stream &operator>> <double>      (Stream &, double &);
template Stream &operator>> <long double> (Stream &, long double &);

// (De)Serialization of C-Style strings
Stream    &operator<<(Stream &stream, const char *str)
{
  uint32  len = (uint32)std::strlen(str) + 1;

  stream << len;
  stream.writeRaw(str, len);
  return (stream);
}
Stream    &operator>>(Stream &stream, char *&str)
{
  uint32  len = 0;

  stream >> len;
  char *buffer = new char[len];
  stream.readRaw(buffer, len);
  str = buffer;
  return (stream);
}

SERY_END_NAMESPACE
```

Comment: You should use network byte order to deal with endianess. See `htonl()` and family. In addition to `Endianess` usally floating point values are not stored in [IEEE-754 Interchange formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_and_interchange_formats) internally. They are usually IEEE-754 but one of the "Extended precision formats" and you can not translate directly to other platforms binary formats. You should convert to one of the standard Interchange formats before writing to your stream.

Comment: Example: On my mac `long double` is 128 bits but only 96 bits are used (because that is the size of the the FP register. On the virtual unix machine I run on my mac. The `long double is 128 bits. But only 80 bits are used. See: https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/src/BinaryRep/FltBinRep.h

Comment: @Morwenn I have updated the question. The first file is now **Sery/Misc.hh**, defining some utils for Sery.

Comment: @LokiAstari Thanks for your feedback. About the endianness, I wanted the user to be able to change it himself. The network's endian is supposed to be Big, isn't it ? Since I thought so, I made `Sery::globalEndian` being `BigEndian` by default.

Comment: @LokiAstari About the floats, I see what you mean. Didn't know it was that different from platforms to others. However, I don't want to copy/paste your code so I'll try to handle it by myself. Thanks again for your comments!

Comment: That's fine. :-)  Just check your platform is using IEEE-754 `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559`. Then check the size of your float with `sizeof()` then check and the number of digits. `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits`. With the size and number of digits you can check if is an IEEE-754 interchange format. If it is then you don't need to do anything. If it is not then unless you really want the support just throw an error. This will wolve 99.99% of situations.

Comment: Very thanks for these tips !
Is `IEEE-754` the most common thing ? It is not a domain I really know. :/

Comment: IEEE-754 is the dominant floating point encoding and will cover 99.99% of situation (but I have no basis for this number just a feeling but it is the most common).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26406/discussion-between-ninetainedo-and-loki-astari).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few notes:

- stop using C-style casts; Better alternative exists
- stop wraping return expressions in parenthesis (every time I see that I think "this is a C-style value cast ... no wait!")
- do not generate code using macros; the namespace macros should only be used if you are going to build on a platform that has no namespace support (are you? you didn't specify)
- your setter and getter for GlobalEndian only set and get the value;

  Better solution: consider setting the value itself public and removing the accessors (they don't add anything and effectively they expose the value as if it were public).

  Even better solution: Ensure that each class has it's own (private) copy of the endianness flag and initialize the private copy upon construction (with a default value); Instances should have no public getter or setter. This is because you cannot change the endianness in the middle of writing to the stream and still expect the written data to be valid.

The way you arrange the code by columns makes it (marginally) easier to read, but over the lifetime of a project, you will either get some tokens out of sync with each other, or have to realign entire lists of functions when you change the length of an identifier; it is debatable  if the extra ease in reading the code is worth it - because once you get used to reading untabulated code, the extra alignment adds nothing but extra maintenance effort).

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I really appreciate it!
I'll answer in different comments to keep things clear. Firstly : about the C-style casts, you're totally right, I should avoid them. But since `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` are so long to write, I think about making proxies functions like `s_c` and `r_c`. But it *really* ruins the readability.

Comment: About return expressions wrapped in parenthesis, I am really used to it. Do you really think it is that bad? I think it really depends on what people are used to.

Comment: The casts are long by design. They are supposed to be large and explicit in code, making them easy to see. Ideally, you should write code that doesn't need them at all; when you use them in a lot of places, that is usually a sign that your architecture and APIs should be improved; As such, usually when you have casts, the solution is to refactor, not to alias them to something smaller (because that doesn't actually solve the problem).

Comment: Code generation using macro is quite useful when it comes to MetaProgramming. However, you are right, there is no point in wrapping the namespace declaration inside a macro like I did there. It simply prevented my IDE from indenting inside the namespace.

Comment: The purpose of the parenthesis is to allow you to write `#define return (x)do_some_operation(x); return x` (or something similar). It is a remnant of old C-style code, from an era when templates and classes didn't exist. In modern code they add nothing (but cruft) because RAII makes such code obsolete.

Comment: About my GlobalEndian, it is meant to allow people to serialize using different endianness easily. For example, if an API is using little endian, they can change the global endian once and it'll change it for each new instance of `Sery::Stream`. However, if they need (in the same project) to read a binary file using big endian, they can still change the local endianness of the specific `Sery::Stream` reading the file. That's what I had in mind. However, it could be specified during construction, you're totally right.

Comment: I figured your intent about the endianness. My point was that there is no scenario when you will change the endianness for an instance, after you have already written into it (so you can set it on construction); Aditionally, you may want to have one instance with one endianness and another instance with the other one. Keeping a static flag will disallow that.

Comment: The static flag is only used inside `Sery::Stream`'s constructor to set the "default" value. But I totally get the point you meant and I'll probably remove the local getter/setter.

Comment: For your last point, I try to align "locally" : for example, I align member functions if they are under the same access specifier. (They may be aligned across different access specifiers but that's an artifact).

Comment: About the **casts**, I thought about using an `union` to prevent their usage. What do you think about this idea ? It would remove the explicit type punning I use to get bytes. However, I feel like I have to cast `size_t` to `uint32` to be sure about its length.

Comment: About the **return**, thanks for the explanation about the original purpose. I learned it this way and it still remains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26402/discussion-between-utnapistim-and-ninetainedo).

Answer (score 2):

Another few notes:

- You can use `#pragma once` instead of include guards. This is a non-standard but widely supported preprocessor directive. Most of the modern compilers support it.
- IMHO, `namespace Sery { }` is much more clearer than `SERY_BEGIN_NAMESPACE / SERY_END_NAMESPACE`. Also consider writing `} // namespace Sery` at the bottom of the file for clarity.
- Consider marking Buffer class as final. Otherwise your `Buffer::~Buffer()` should have been either either public and virtual, or protected and non-virtual (Sutter's rule). The same for `Stream` class.
- I also agree with @utnapistim about code formatting.
- The leading underscores for private members do not break any rules, but it is close to it (e.g. if you start an identifier with a capital letter). Consider using trailing underscore for that matter. You'll get used to it soon.

Comment: I don't really like `pragma once` because it is non-standard. I try to avoid non-standard things as much as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I will remove the `#define SERY_BEGIN_NAMESPACE` from the code and use the "classical" way.

Comment: You're right, I should have made `Sery::Buffer` and `Sery::Stream` final since they are not meant to be inherited from.

Comment: About the leading underscore, as you said, it doesn't break any rule. Thus, I don't feel bad about doing it. I like it in front of the name because it allows me to know instantly where it comes from when I read the code.

Comment: Btw, if you don't trust `#pragma once` because it's non-standard, you should consider using it in combination with include guards. It saves compilation time. If `#pragma once` is supported, compiler will stop parsing the file as soon as the directive is found, which is not the case for include guards.

Answer (score 0):

reinterpret_cast to `uint8*` violates strict aliasing rules and lead to undefined behavior. Use `char*` as it is granted exception in the standard.